# Adding column result based on awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to sum the result of this query which takes the HTTP error codes from access.log and sets out the total occurrences for each code:

```
awk '{print $9}' access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Result:

```
234 200
3   500
102 404
26 304
3 404
```

Trying to figure out what's the best way to sum up the result (column 1 = 234+3+102+26+3)

Thanks.

Comment: That's not the result I'd expect from that command, it's not sorted.

Comment: The sum is just `wc -l access.log`

Comment: GNU datamash is handy for this sort of thing: `datamash -Ws -g9 count 9 < access.log`. And `wc -l access.log` for the total?

Comment: If you could post samples of input then probably we could do this in a single awk also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single awk solution, removing the need to any piping to sort or uniq. Using GNU awk:

```
awk '$9 ~ /[[:digit:]]{3}/ { err[$9]+=1 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for (i in err) { tot=tot+err[i];print i" - "err[i]} printf "\nTOT - %s\n",tot }' access.log
```

First we check that the 9th space delimited field is in the correct format for an HTTP code (3 digits). If this is the case, we set up an array called err with the code as the index which is incremented every time the code is encountered. Once all lines are processed, we sort the array in value, number, ascending order and we loop through the entries printing the code and the total. We also set a running total in the variable tot. We finally print this tot at the end of the output.

Comment: No problem. If you are happy with the solution, please accept it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it to another `awk` command that prints the lines and calculates the total.

```
awk '{print $9}' access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{total += $1; print} END {print total, "Total"}'
```